# Nginx: redirect mydomain.com to mydomain.es on DigitalOcean VPS

Tags: nginx

I have a working mydomain.com domain already working on a DigitalOcean VPS, I serve it using Nginx.

Now I bought mydomain.es and added the DNS to point to my DigitalOcean VPS, and I want it to redirect to mydomain.com, how can I do it with nginx?

This is my nginx file for mydomain.com domain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;


    root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/mydomain.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/mydomain.com/error.log;


    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really just want to 301 redirect all traffic to the existing mydomain.com?

Then you could simply add a new server block (normally in a separate config file):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.es www.mydomain.es;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Notice: This is only redirecting non-SSL traffic to standard port 80. You'd normally add a separate server block for SSL traffic to port 443.

Comment: interesting, can you show me how to do it for 443?

Comment: The redirect part is exactly the same but with `listen 443`. But you'll need some more configuration for HTTPS to work correctly, like the used ssl ciphers, certificate path and so on. Read on here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html